# Have just got new Dell Laptop with IE9 and cannot use any of my email accounts

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I Have just got new Dell Laptop with IE9 and cannot use any of my email accounts (sky or hotmail. When I go to the Sky login the URL line is green. If I type my password and username it just returns a blanck screen. For the hotmail sign in it is still green and does not even offer me the login sreen. Can any one help?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with javascript, cookie or restricted site settings? You may try opening the options dialog and on the Security tab set the lowest possible security level. Anyway If you don't mind using a different browser, even just for diagnostic purpose, try to install from scratch something like Google Chrome and repeat again the process to see if the problems still remains unsolved.